# Кросс-компиляция на Qt5

Tags: qt5, raspberry-pi, embedded, кросс-компиляция

Есть Raspberry Pi 2 и Qt5.
Собрал по [вот этому мануалу](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step).
Что очень удобно (раньше, устанавливал на Rpi2 и через SSH работал).

Возникло ряд проблем, которые я уже 2 дня не могу решить, 1-я:

> Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
>   To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).

Не соответствие экранов. Пробовал прописывать в `.bashrc`:

```
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH=108

export QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT=65
```

Никакого эффекта, ни положительного, ни отрицательного.
Пробовал ставить `setFixedSize(800, 480);` - тоже никакого эффекта.

Как решить проблему?

2-я проблема:
При запуске программы, её не видно через VNC. То есть, глядя на экран я её вижу, она работает, но через VNC не видно ничего, просто рабочий стол и выхлоп в терминале. Внешне похоже, что VNC и мои программы работают на разных уровнях и друг друга не видят.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518280/raspberry-pi-qt5-set-physical-screen-size

Comment: Я же написал, не работает! Всё это я пробовал.

Comment: У вас две переменные, а там три.

Comment: Я добавлял и depth. Никакого эффекта.

Comment: Проблему в итоге решил?
у меня такая же проблема возникла.